# Perfect numbers using java programming

Tags: java

Hellooo I'm trying to display all the perfect numbers between 1 and and integer entered by the user and its factors. I got the code working fine It's just that my output doesn't quite match the output I desired...

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;    

public class PerfectNumbers {       
    public static boolean isPerfect(int a) {            
        int n = a; 
        int sum = 0; 
        boolean perfect; 

        while (n-- >1) {                
            if(a%n==0) 
                sum = sum + n; 
            }   
            if (sum == a) { 
                perfect = true; 
            } else { 
                perfect = false; 
            } 
            return perfect; 
        } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter the number up to which you would like to look for perfect numbers:"); 
        int i = input.nextInt(); 
        String factors = "";        
        System.out.printf("Looking for perfect numbers from 1 to %d%n", i);

        while (i > 0) { 
            if (PerfectNumbers.isPerfect(i) == true) {
                int w = i-1; 
                while (w-- > 1) {
                    if(i % w == 0) 
                        factors = factors + " " + Integer.toString(w); 
                } 
                System.out.println(i + " is a perfect number it's factors are:" + factors); 
            } 
            i = i - 1; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

This is what my output returns
[image: This is what my output returns]

But I want it to display this instead

[image: But I want it to display this instead]

Comment: You have to reset `factors` to an empty string after each perfect number

Comment: How would I "reset" the factors? Does this mean equate it to an empty string? I am a beginner so I am not sure yet

Comment: Instead of `while(i > 0)`, add `int j = 1;` and change the condition to `while(j <= i)`. Also change `i = i - 1;` to `j = j + 1;`. That will fix the ordering.

Comment: I attempted your suggestion but ended up with this output:Enter the number up to which you would like to look for perfect numbers:500
Looking for perfect numbers from 1 to 500
8128 is a perfect number it's factors are: 4064 2032 1016 508 254 127 64 32 16 8 4 2 1

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to take the rest of the code into account. What if you change `isPerfect(i)` to `isPerfect(j)`, change `int w = i-1;` to `int w = 1;`, change `while(w-- > 1)` to `while(w++ < i)`, change `if(i % w == 0)` to `if(j % w == 0)`, and change `System.out.println(i + ...)` to `System.out.println(j + ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

do one think in your code
add this in `factors = "";` in while loop

here is working code

```
    public class PerfectNumbers { 

    public static boolean isPerfect(int a) { 
        int n = a; 
        int sum = 0; 
        boolean perfect = false; 

        while (n-- >1) {
            if(a%n==0) {
                sum = sum + n; 
            }   
            if (sum == a) { 
                perfect = true; 
            } else { 
                perfect = false; 
            } 
        }
        return perfect;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter the number up to which you would like to look for perfect numbers:"); 
        int i = input.nextInt(); 
        String factors = ""; 
        System.out.printf("Looking for perfect numbers from 1 to %d%n", i);
        while (i > 0) { 
            if (PerfectNumbers.isPerfect(i) == true) {
                int w = i-1; 
                while (w-- > 1) {
                   if(i % w == 0)
                   factors = factors + " " + Integer.toString(w);                  
                } 
                System.out.println(i + " is a perfect number it's factors are:" + factors); 
                factors = "";
            } 
            i = i - 1; 
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of interest here's a Java 8 stream-based solution:

```
public class PerfectNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.range(1, 500)
                .filter(n -> factors(n).sum() == n)
                .forEach(n -> System.out.println(n + " is a prefect numbers its factors are "
                    + factors(n).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" "))));
    }

    private static IntStream factors(int n) {
        return IntStream.range(1, n).filter(d -> n % d == 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Should it be written like this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PerfectNumbers {

    public static boolean isPerfect(int a) {

        int n = a;
        int sum = 0;
        boolean perfect;

        while (n-- > 1) {

            if (a % n == 0)
                sum = sum + n;

        }
        if (sum == a) {

            perfect = true;

        } else {

            perfect = false;

        }

        return perfect;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number up to which you would like to look for perfect numbers:");
        int i = input.nextInt();
        String factors = "";

        System.out.printf("Looking for perfect numbers from 1 to %d%n", i);

        for (int j = 1; j < i + 1; j++) {

            if (PerfectNumbers.isPerfect(i) == true) {

                int w = i - 1;

                for (j = 1; j < i + 1; j++) {

                    if (i % w == 0)
                        factors = factors + " " + Integer.toString(w);

                }
                System.out.println(i + " is a perfect number it's factors are:" + factors);
            }
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This code works fine. it gives as output as you expected..
public class PerfectNumbers {

```
public static boolean isPerfect(int a) { 

    int n = a; 
    int sum = 0; 
    boolean perfect; 

    while (n-- >1) {

        if(a%n==0) 
            sum = sum + n; 

    }   
    if (sum == a) 
    { 

        perfect = true; 

    } 
    else 
    { 

        perfect = false; 

    } 

        return perfect; 

    } 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.print("Enter the number up to which you would like to look for perfect numbers:"); 
    int i = input.nextInt(); 


    System.out.println("Looking for perfect numbers from 1 to "+i);
    int inc = 1;
    while (inc < i) { 

        if (PerfectNumbers.isPerfect(inc) == true) {
            String factors = "";
            int w = inc-1; 
            int j = 1;
            while (j < w) {

                if(inc % j == 0) 
                    factors = factors + " " + Integer.toString(j); 

                j++;
            } 
            System.out.println(inc + " is a perfect number it's factors are:" + factors); 

        } 
        inc = inc + 1; 
    }
    input.close();
}
```

}

Comment: To avoid memory leak close your resources once they are done.

Comment: why it is not useful

Comment: What is memory leak? and how do I close my resources?

Comment: welcome.. memory leak is a failure in a program to release discarded memory, causing impaired performance or failure. By using close() method or by using IOUtils..

Answer (score -2):

You loop in reverse order, say from 1000 to zero. Change your

```
    while (i>0)
```

With

```
    for (int j=1;j<i+1;j++)
```

Same thing for the loop on factors

EDIT

Solution Proposal, only changes are in the method main

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

   System.out.print("Enter the number up to which you would like to look for perfect numbers:"); 
   int inp = input.nextInt(); 


   System.out.printf("Looking for perfect numbers from 1 to %d%n", inp);

   for(int j=1;j<inp+1;j++) { 

      if (PerfectNumbers.isPerfect(j) == true) {


         String factors = "";   
         for (int w=1; w<j;w++) {

         if(j % w == 0) 
            factors = factors + " " + Integer.toString(w); 

      } 
      System.out.println(j + " is a perfect number it's factors are:" + factors); 
    } 

    } 
}
```

Comment: `While` and `For` are not keywords in Java. And the problem is that the program is showing *wrong* output (248 is not a factor of 6), not that the output is in the wrong order.

Comment: Actually the problem is that the program is showing the wrong output and wrong order:/ haha

Comment: I replaced the while loop with the for loop you provided however, I'm still getting the wrong output

Comment: Now you print them in correct order. What is the algo for perfect number ?

Comment: [Perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number). And you still need to edit your answer. Java is case sensitive.

Comment: System.out.println(i + " is a perfect number it's factors are:" + factors); Wont print out the perfect numbers?

Comment: See my answer with a proposal for solution